# Why doesn't Heathrow T5 have stand 504?

Tags: airport-design

On the North side of Terminal 5A are four stands, 501, 502, 503, and 505. Why is there no 504?

[image: Image showing the North side of terminal 5A at Heathrow, stands 501, 502, 503, and 505 are shown.]

Comment: And 510 is also missing…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stand numbers at Heathrow correspond to the terminal and gate numbers. The first digit of the stand number is '5' for all terminal 5 stands, and the last 2 digits correspond to the gate number. So, the missing stands 504 and 510 would correspond to gates A4 and A10 respectively.

According [to unverified (by me) reports on flyertalk.com](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1656769-flights-departing-gates-a4-a10-heathrow-terminal-5-a.html), Gates A4 and A10 are exclusively "bus gates" where passengers board a bus rather than accessing via a jet bridge. So there is no corresponding stand next to the gate.

Comment: What is the purpose of a bus gate on A4 and A10, is it in case an arrival expected at the A gates gets parked remotely for some reason?

Comment: @opr Such "airside transfers" are used at many airports. As for the logistical rationale... I'm not really sure! I think that would make a great standalone question if you care to post it.